# c++ specifying data length with data type declaration

Tags: c++

I came across this syntax which i have not seen before

```
struct A {
    int x:24;
};
```

What does x:24 mean ? In C++ can you specify compiler that a variable should occupy only 24 bits, instead of 32 for an int type?
If yes, which 24 bits will be occupied? the left most or the right most?

Comment: x would make a very curious int if it was the MSB part of a standard systems int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [bit fields feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). It has been available since the early C days. Microsoft has [a nice write-up on this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), complete with pretty pictures showing the layout which is compiler-specific (they say that the pic is specific to MS).

Comment: unsigned           : 0;  Is an interesting feature I had not realized before.

Comment: But note that the pretty pictures only describe how Microsoft chose to implement it; in general, the layout is implementation defined.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are absolutely correct: this very point was the subject of my edit.

Comment: What is difference between int x:8; and char x ? When to use one over other ?

Comment: @Jimm My understanding is that using `char` in between of two `int:...` bit fields forces re-alignment. For example, the size of `struct Bits1 {int x:16; int y:8; int z:8; }` is 4, but the size of seemingly equivalent `struct Bits2 {int x:16; char y; int z:8; }` is 12.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what you think it is, called a *bit field*. `x` has 24 bit available.

```
// standard 32bit integer:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
// x (24 bit):
0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
//        ^ -- cut off here
// other 8 bit available for other uses, for example:

struct A{
  int x : 24;
  int y : 8;
}; // sizeof(A) == sizeof(int) (most likely on 32bit architecture)
```

Note that the struct will still be 32 bit (or 4 byte) big, since you can't just cut off those excess bit. As such, bit fields are mostly useful when you have *very tight space requirements* and need to pack as much information as possible into as little space as possible.

Comment: If you'd care to elaborate with a guess; Is the compiler implementation a mask + bitshift in these scenarios?    (bitshift)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Most likely. On the hardware level, you can't tear apart words in any other way IIRC. It's interesting to note, however, that any overflows from one bit field do not affect any other bit field (if `x` would overflow, `y` would not change) (apart from the fact that in this case, the overflow would be undefined behaviour because `x` is signed...).

Comment: In your example above, will there be a padding after int x:24 to keep the int aligned to 32 bits or will the remainder 8 bits from the variable x, used to fill in value for variable Y?

Comment: Also, in your above example, if the value of y can fit in 8 bits, is int y:8 , equivalent as char y (where char is  8 bits long)?

Comment: @Jimm: Yes, the remaining 8 bits `x` left over will be used for `y`, as can be seen by my assertion that `sizeof(A) == sizeof(int)` (with 32bit `int`). I don't, however, think that you can use a `char` instead.

Answer (score 4):

> If yes, which 24 bits will be occupied? the left most or the right most?

It is unspecified in the C++ standard (§9.6/1: *Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others*).

Usually it depends on the endianness of the platform. On a little-endian platform it would be filled as:

```
[ bits 0~7 ] [ bits 8~15 ] [ bits 16~23 ] [ bits 24~31 ]
----------------------------------------- --------------
                    x                         (padding)
```

and reversed in big-endian platform

```
[ bits 0~7 ] [ bits 8~15 ] [ bits 16~23 ] [ bits 24~31 ]
------------ -------------------------------------------
  (padding)                       x
```

Comment: How does compiler align a struct with bit fields? Will it simply pad enough bits on the end of the struct, so that it is aligned on 32 bits for a 32 bit platform?  What if a struct has one bit field like int x:8 and another regular field int y; where would the padding be applied in this example?

Comment: @Jimm: You can see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provided by [@dasblinkenlight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900155/224671)

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of bits would be CPU Dependent. Maybe you could write something simple like 1 to this field and then look at the memory word in the debugger.

Comment: I would imagine that the compiler would be doing the heavy lifting here, not the cpu.